# CPLEX DOcplexException on Mac big sur(M1)

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, installation, cplex, docplex

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

opt_model = Model(name = 'Linear Program')

x = opt_model.continuous_var(name = 'x', lb = 0)
y = opt_model.continuous_var(name = 'y', lb = 0)

c1 = opt_model.add_constraint(x + y >= 8, ctname = 'c1')
c2 = opt_model.add_constraint(2*x + y >= 10, ctname = 'c2')
c3 = opt_model.add_constraint(x + 4*y >= 11, ctname = 'c3')

obj_fn = 5 * x + 4 * y
opt_model.set_objective('min', obj_fn)
opt_model.print_information()

opt_model.solve()
```

When I run the above code, it shows this error **DOcplexException: Cannot solve model: no CPLEX runtime found.**

I am using MacOS(M1) Big Sur. When I run **python -m docplex.mp.check_list** on the terminal, I got this output.

" * system is: Darwin 64bit

- Python version 3.9.7, located at: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python
- docplex is present, version is 2.23.221
- CPLEX library is not available
- pandas is present, version is 1.3.3
  Cplex runtime not found, error importing cplex: dlopen(/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/python/3.9/x86-64_osx/cplex/_internal/py39_cplex2210.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/python/3.9/x86-64_osx/cplex/_internal/py39_cplex2210.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
  /Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/python/3.9/x86-64_osx/cplex/_internal/py39_cplex2210.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
- diagnostics: 1
  -- No local installation of CPLEX has been found. "

I tried to set pythonpath, but that does not help.

**Solved: I just installed a new cplex version (CPLEX 22.1.1 osx arm64) and it worked in Macos Monterey.**

Comment: having the same issue and I installed cplex

Comment: @Kashif , Can you share installation procedure?

Comment: I ran `python /Applications/CPLEX_Studio201/python/setup.py install` after installing CPLEX on my MacBook.

Comment: But when I try to do any modeling, I get errors that cplex isn't found.

Comment: @Kashif Same here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892000/cplex-22-1-python-api-on-macbook-with-m1-architecture/74893489#74893489

Comment: @AlexFleischer, thanks it works. I am able to successfully install CPLEX 22.1.1 in Macos Monterey.